# Twilio REST api sequential calling possible?

Tags: php, api, rest, twilio

After a while of writing REST api and TwiML apps I had been trying to write a sequential Dialing app in REST api but after much errors and issues I am stumped. I had written a sequential dialing app in TwiML but writing the same app in REST is hell....

What I have been trying to do in REST api is create this program where a person A has a list of people B C D E F G H I J K, person A wants to send an SMS to a twilio number, Twilio would then call using REST api to the list of people one by one until one of them pick up. The Process goes like this:

```
    1) Person A text's Twilio number
    2) Twilio gathers its array of phone numbers of persons B C D E F G H I J K
    3) Twilio's REST api calls person B
    4) Person B does **NOT** pick up (busy or doesn't pick up so answering machine) so then REST api calls person C next
    5) Person C does **NOT** pick up (busy or doesn't pick up so answering machine) so then the REST api calls person D
    6) Person D **DOES** pick up and twilio **reads the SMS sent by person A and then hangs up**
    7) application ends, so person E F G H I J K are not called because one person picked up so **not everyone** had to be called
```

I am trying to make this in REST api but after hours of trying I have given up...My only question is: is this possible with [REST api](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest)? if so how?

I have been able to make an app where I sms twilio, twilio calls back with REST api and reads me the SMS but sequential dialling is so different...

I have tried talking to Twilio staff but I have not been able to figure out a way to make the sequential calling work as I don't know what else to do....I have tried using StatusCallback and much more but now I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Here's a rough outline of what needs to be done:

### SMS Script

This is what you point the Twilio number's SMS to. It should take the `Body` parameter and store it to a database (because somehow you'll need to persist this over multiple requests). It will also need to grab the list of numbers that should be calls (presumably from a database or a common config file).

Once the body is stored, the SMS script should initiate a call to the first number on the list with the 'Redial Script' as the `StatusCallback`, and the 'Message' script as the `Url`.

Add an `id` parameter to the `StatusCallback` and the `Url` (using the query string should be fine), so those scripts can identify the message that should be played.

### Redial Script

This handles working through the list, it should check the `CallStatus` to see if the call was answered. If it was, then simply exit. If not, it works through the list of numbers (again, pulled from a database or common config file) until it matches the `To` parameter to a nubmer in the list.

Once that match is made, the script should initiate a call to the *next* number on the list, again using the 'Redial Script' as the `StatusCallback`, and the 'Message' script as the `Url` passing the message `id` to both scripts as a parameter.

### Message Script

This is the script Twilio requests when the call is answered, it simply checks the `id` parameter, pulls the message from the database, and reads it.

Note that using a database isn't *necessary* you could pass the full message instead of an id. You could also replace the message script with a [Twimlet](http://labs.twilio.com/twimlets/message).